# How to reduce the time to get the data from sharepoint list in POPUP?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, development

I am getting the data from sharepoint list and displaying in popup.My sharepoint list having 4000 items.
  So it was taking too much time(5 minutes) to load the data.
  How we can reduce the time ?

My code:

```
enter code here function OpenPopContractingParty2(PageURL) {

        var options = {
            url: PageURL + "&Selectedvalue=" + document.getElementById('<%=txtCounterParties.ClientID %>').value.replace("'", "~") + "&CT=" + document.getElementById('<%=hdnType.ClientID %>').value,

            title: "Contracting Party Picker",
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true
        };
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

        function CloseCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtCounterParties.ClientID %>').focus();
            if (returnValue != null && returnValue != "") {
                document.getElementById('<%=hdnContractingParty2Source.ClientID %>').value = returnValue.replace("~", "'").split(';')[1];
                document.getElementById('<%=txtCounterParties.ClientID %>').value = returnValue.replace("~", "'").split(';')[0];
                var sval = '<%=ContractTitle%>'
                var vendor = '<% = Resources.eContractsExtended.Vendor_NotAvailable%>';
                var strTitle = sval + returnValue.replace("~", "'");
                strTitle = strTitle.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
                var strNewTitle = strTitle.replace(".", "");
                var strNewTitle1 = strNewTitle.replace("&", "");
                if (document.getElementById('<%=txtRequestToContract.ClientID %>').value == "") {
                    if (document.getElementById('<%=txtCounterParties.ClientID %>').value != vendor) {
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtContractTitle.ClientID %>').value = returnValue.replace("~", "'").split(';')[2];
                        document.getElementById('<%=hdnCounterparty.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtCompany.ClientID %>').value;

                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtContractTitle.ClientID %>').value = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            if (document.getElementById('<%=rbOriginatorExternal.ClientID %>').checked)
                document.getElementById('<%=txtOriginatingParty.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtCounterParties.ClientID %>').value
        }
    }

<asp:Menu ID="menuTab" Width="168px" runat="server" RenderingMode="Table" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
    StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="tab" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selectedTab"
    OnMenuItemClick="menuTab_MenuItemClick" CssClass="tabs">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="<%$Resources:eContractsExtended,Search_Counterparties_Title%>" Value="0"
            Selected="true" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="<%$Resources:eContractsExtended,CP_My_Company_Entities%>" Value="1"
            Selectable="true" />

    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in SharePoint modal dialog but on your page. Please open this page normally, not in a modal dialog. I suppose you have to also wait long time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `options.url` is a custom page and you need to reduce the load time on that page by

1. Paging (display only 30 items max on each paged view)
2. Add indexes on the list columns that are used in the filter. Example add an index on the CT column.

As @Peter said open the page in browser and make sure it loads faster. Then test the popup dialog.

Hope that helps!